# How do I make the "Created by [Me]" filter work after saving a list as a template

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, filter

I created a list from a template where one of the views is filtered using the "[Me]" value of the "Created By field" so users can only view their entry and their entry only.  Now, in the new list I created from the template, the "Created By" are all shown as myself and not the folks who originally created the item.

Since I found out you can't change the "Created By" field, is there another way or view that can single out items that the users created and not see anyone elses?

Answer (score 0):

To make user can only see items created by himself and not see anyone else, you can modify view->set filter like: Created By is equal to [Me]:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is correct however, my issue is, I saved from a template along with the data and now each item in the new copy is showing me as created by.  I need to bring over the created by from the old data...maybe upload via Excel?